# while loop with try/exception stay in loop until read all rows of df / ignore exception

Tags: python, while-loop, git-clone, try-except

Here is a piece of Python that got stuck on the exception loop. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595199/stay-in-while-loop-after-an-exception) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369827/using-continue-in-a-try-and-except-inside-while-loop) and many more and unfortunately could not find the answer I am looking for. It works fine until it gets stuck in exception for i=8 (i.e. the [git_url](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_theme) is archived by owner). How can I solve it? I don't want it to break/get_stuck when i=8 because it still needs to read the rest.

```
i=7
while i<10:
  try:
    Repo.clone_from(df.git_url[i],repo_dir) #clone repositores for each url
  except:
    print("error")
    continue
  else:
      for f in glob.iglob("repo_dir/**/*.rb"):
        txt = open(f, "r") 
        # let's say txt is a code file that I want to extract data from 
        for line in txt:
            print(line)  
  shutil.rmtree(repo_dir)
  os.makedirs(repo_dir)
  i+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once `continue` is called, it will skip back to the top before `i += 1` is called. Try moving that statement higher up, something like:

```
i=7
while i<10:
  try:
    Repo.clone_from(df.git_url[i],repo_dir) #clone repositores for each url
  except:
    print("error")
    i += 1
    continue
  else:
      for f in glob.iglob("repo_dir/**/*.rb"):
        txt = open(f, "r") 
        # let's say txt is a code file that I want to extract data from 
        for line in txt:
            print(line)  
  shutil.rmtree(repo_dir)
  os.makedirs(repo_dir)
  i += 1
```

That way it won't get stuck on the problematic iteration, let me know how this goes :)

Comment: Thanks, it works. I should have asked earlier.

Comment: It's easy to get lost in rabbit holes debugging code :P